# Php with .bat and parameters

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file

I'm working on a web to make back ups and restores of the phpmyAdmin databases (actually just one db) I made two .bat files to execute them from a php file with `exec(file.bat)` the first one has the name backup.bat and it contains this code:

`Set Fecha=%Date:~0,2%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~6,4%
Set Hora=%Time:~0,2%%Time:~3,2%
mysqldump -u root --password="" dbceleues > C:\xampp\htdocs\SysWebCELEUES\BackUp\dbceleues%Fecha%%Hora%.sql` 
and I'm having some issues trying to execute the second file "restore.bat" I upload the dbceleues.sql with an input file on the form and I get with the method "Post" this:

```
$file=$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$name=$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
```

then I do this:

```
chdir('C:\xampp\mysql\bin');
exec("restore.bat",$name);
```

or this:

```
chdir('C:\xampp\mysql\bin');
exec("restore.bat",$file);
```

I have modified the file with this code for the first exec: `mysql -u root --password=""  -B dbceleues < C:\xampp\htdocs\SysWebCELEUES\BackUp\%1%`

and for the second the file contains this:

```
mysql -u root --password=""  -B dbceleues < %1%
```

the problem is it appears, the parameter isn't recieved no matter what I do, only if I put the location static like this:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\SysWebCELEUES\BackUp\dbceleues200120161245.sql` the bat works perfectly!
So, the problem is to try to send a parameter to the .bat file
Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exec() not pass the second parameter to the command. Please check [php manual for function exec](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php)

You should call it like this:

```
exec("restore.bat $file");
```

Or even better:

```
exec('restore.bat "' . $file . '"');
```

And in batch files argument variables only use a percent sign before the number like this:

```
mysql -u root --password=""  -B dbceleues < %1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my day! I even messed with the apache service... Once again thanks!!!